# how can I set timeout for each request in asynchronous C++ client for gRPC?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, timeout, grpc

I used asynchronous C++ client for gRPC，but I can't set timeout for each request，when I used synchronous client, I can set the timeout through the ClientContext.set_deadline()，but this method does not take effect in asynchronous client；

I worried about when the gRPC server crash， then some request will be in the completion queue for ever, however I hope that when the request in the completion queue did not receive a response within a specified period of time ， then it can notify that the request is timeout.

how can I achieve this goal？

waiting for your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the issue completely, but you should be able to set the deadline for the RPC using set_deadline on the ClientContext before you start the call. 
After the deadline expires, the completion queue Next operation should return with a timeout.